# JestElasticsearchException in jhipster

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I m using JHipster 6.7.1.
I made a standard installation with elasticsearch option.
once Jhipser is started , while trying to search, it throws an exception:

```
JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [id] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"Bhyc9vkhReOznQW5Py_7zA","index":"magician"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"dfs","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magician","node":"fXRR6Sn3TPqTS705SBZfDw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [id] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"Bhyc9vkhReOznQW5Py_7zA","index":"magician"}}]} , message : null
```

I only found this: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10003

Is it related? is there a solution ?

thanks for your help!

Comment: can u provide ur elasticsearch index mapping and your search query?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, here is the request : http://localhost:8080/api/_search/publishers?query=ds&page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc and the response (500) {"type":"https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message","title":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"detail":"Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [id] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"SgAW6bXpSI2gfKZTHJI5sg\"

Comment: I got the error message, info you provided in the comment is already present in your question, I asked for elasticsearch index mapping and your search query

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is occurring is because you do not have any data in the index you are searching on. Try adding records to your jhipster project via API calls or the UI ('Create' button) and then try the search bar; jhipster automatically indexes the data during API calls. It will not, however, automatically index data that is manually loaded into the database.